# @@@ @@@ in hyperlink renders parially

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a listview which has a hyperlink in the item template, the hyperlink contains labels for my text(tried direct text to hyperlink also but got the same result).

The code is like below

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="SampleListview" OnItemDataBound="Listview_ItemDataBound">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemplaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>        
                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="URL">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label" runat="server" />
                </asp:HyperLink>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:ListView>
```

On the item data bound I have added code for htmlEncode and decode so that the HTML tags don't render on the application.

```
Label.text = HttpUtility.HTMLDecode(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(datarow.Value));
```

My problem is that this code works fine with  and normal text, but when the text is `@@@@ @@@@` my output shows only `@@@@`. Upon removing the hyperlinks my issue was fixed.

Thinking the issue is related to hyperlink I have created a fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/uf9nbp8s/ but it works fine here and I have no clear explanation as to why the behaviour is the way I am seeing on application.

Comment: What does the actual rendered html look like? I suspect your markup is broken.

Comment: the markup also shows the same that I can see on the page @@@ only and not @@@@ @@@@.